# How to calculate share rate with dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataset as I've shown below:

```
data <- tribble(
  ~id,     ~click,  ~engagement,
   1,         1,          0,
   2,         2,          3,         
   3,         3,          5,
   4,         4,          6, 
   5,         5,          2,
   6,         3,          4,
   7,         8,          7,
   8,         6,          1,
   9,         7,          6,
  10,         7,          3,
)
```

My desired data is something like this:

```
new_data <- tribble(
  ~total_click,  ~total_engagement, ~percantage_click, ~percantage_engagement, 
     46,              37,              0.5542169,          0.4457831,
)
```

I was able to get total_click and total_engagement by coding like this:

```
data %>% 
  summarise(total_click = sum(click), total_engagement = sum(engagement))
```

How can I get the percentage?

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
data %>% 
  summarise(total_click = sum(click), total_engagement = sum(engagement), 
            percantage_click=total_click/(total_click+total_engagement), 
            percantage_engagement=1- percantage_click)
```

***Data:***

```
data <- tribble(
  ~id,     ~click,  ~engagement,
  1,         1,          0,
  2,         2,          3,         
  3,         3,          5,
  4,         4,          6, 
  5,         5,          2,
  6,         3,          4,
  7,         8,          7,
  8,         6,          1,
  9,         7,          6,
  10,         7,          3,
)
```

Answer (score 3):

```
data %>%
    summarize_at(vars(-id), sum) %>%
    mutate(click_p = click/(click + engagement),
           engagement_p = 1 - click_p)
## A tibble: 1 x 4
#  click engagement click_p engagement_p
#  <dbl>      <dbl>   <dbl>        <dbl>
#1    46         37   0.554        0.446
```

Answer (score 2):

We can also do it like this:

```r
data %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(-id), list(sum)) %>% 
  bind_cols(. / rowSums(.))
```